# saving multiple charts in one document

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts

I'm looking for a way to save 3 different charts in one document.
My program calculates some data and this data will be shown in 3 different charts
I have chart1, chart2 and chart3
I found this code, it's only working to save 1 chart as an image in one document

```
01  ' Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Image
02         ' assigned to Button2.
03         Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
04         saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif       Image|*.gif"
05         saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File"
06         saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
07   
08         ' If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
09         If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
10             ' Saves the Image via a FileStream created by the OpenFile method.
11             Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = CType _
12                (saveFileDialog1.OpenFile(), System.IO.FileStream)
13             ' Saves the Image in the appropriate ImageFormat based upon the
14             ' file type selected in the dialog box.
15             ' NOTE that the FilterIndex property is one-based.
16             Select Case saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex
17                 Case 1
18                     Chart1.SaveImage(fs, _
19                        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
20   
21                 Case 2
22                     Chart1.SaveImage(fs, _
23                        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
24   
25                 Case 3
26                     Chart1.SaveImage(fs, _
27                        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
28             End Select
```

Does anyone have other suggestion to save 3 different chart on one document by clicking a button in my vb.net program?

Answer (score 0):

You should write each chart out to a file:

```
Chart1.SaveImage(fs & 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Chart2.SaveImage(fs & 2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Chart3.SaveImage(fs & 3, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

The create a new drawing from those files, using Graphics.DrawImage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42807xh1.aspx_

You can then save this compilation of images in one file, using Image.Save (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Have fun!

Comment: That's beyond my expertise. The first link doesn't work. I have tryed your suggestion, but it didn;t work for me